# The cartesian product of contractible spaces is contractible

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, higher-homotopy-groups

Let $X_i$, $i\in I$ be contractible spaces. Is the Cartesian product $\prod_iX_i$ contractible, too?

Answer (score 1):

Since $X_i$ is contractible, there exists a continuous map $h_i\colon X_i\times [0,1]\to X_i$ such that $h_i(x,0)=x$ and $h_i(x,1)=x^0_i$ for some $x^0_i\in X_i$ for all $x\in X_i$. Define
$$X = \prod_i X_i,\quad\text{and}\quad H\colon X\times [0,1]\to X,\ H\left((x_i)_i,t\right) = (h_i(x_i,t))_i.$$ This function is continuous.
Moreover, $$H((x_i)_i,0)=(h_i(x_i,0))_i = (x_i)_i$$ and
$$H((x_i)_i,1)=(h_i(x_i,1))_i = (x^0_i)_i,$$ therefore $H$ is a homotopy joining identity to a constant map.

**Proof of the continuity**
For $i\in I$ let $\pi_i\colon X\to X_i$ be a projection. Then
$$\pi_i\circ H = h_i\circ (\pi_i\times \mathrm{id}_{[0,1]}).$$ Therefore $\pi_i\circ H$ is continuous for all $i\in I$.

Comment: This is precisely the proof I was trying to avoid since it uses contracting homotopies, which I have only seen defined in topospaces.subwiki. Can you reformulate the proof using the standard definition of contractible, namely, $X$ is contractible if its identity is null-homotopic.

Comment: The statement *its identity map is null-homotopic* means that there exists a homotopy from the identity map to a constant map, which is exactly what this answer uses (and is exactly what is used in the answer of the duplicate post linked above).